# Replicate with Google Script the behaviour of "File" > "Download as..." in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to either:

a) replace "**File**" > "**Download as...**" > "**Microsoft Excel (.xlsx)**" in Google Spreadsheet in such a way that when I click on "Microsoft Excel (.xlsx)" it asks me for the name of the file that I want to save (i.e.: like a typical "**Save as...**" menu entry).

b) if it's not possible to replace the standard menu entry, I would like at least to add another menu entry in another menu which behaves like described above.

Even though I haven't been able to write a script that lets me replace an existing menu entry, I've managed to write a script that adds an additional menu.

Is it possible to accomplish "a"?

---

Another problem now is that I can't seem to find a way to **replicate the behaviour** of "File" > "Download as..." > "Microsoft Excel (.xlsx)".

I've found other posts in which it's described how to write Google Scripts in order to do something similar (e.g.: create a backup of a spreadsheet in **Google Drive** in a specific format, or send it via **GMail** to a specific address).

Actually, after reading "[Can I download file from URL link generated by google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573055/can-i-download-file-from-url-link-generated-by-google-apps-script)" I'm not even sure it's possible.

> Note that you cannot download per se, since you have no access to your
>   PC's resources (e.g. file system) from apps-script. The file is still
>   in "the cloud"... in this case, it's been copied from the web site it
>   was on, into Google Drive. If you're running the Drive app, though,
>   the file will now sync to your PC.

Is there any way to do that?

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you actually answered your own question yourself... and there is indeed no way to change the default menus in a Google document.

Comment: How about the second point? Is it possible to replicate the behaviour of "File" > "Download as..." > "Microsoft Excel (.xlsx)"?

Comment: As you mentioned: "...you can not download per se..." you can just use the drive.app workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I achieved download of a file from the spreadsheet is by writing completely separate script which accessed my original spreadsheet by document id, generated a file and downloaded it like this:

```
function doGet(){
    var outputDocument = DocumentApp.create('Some csv'); 
    var content = getCsv();
    var textContent = ContentService.createTextOutput(content);
    textContent.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.CSV);
    textContent.downloadAsFile("4NocniMaraton.csv");
    return textContent;
}
```

Then I had to publish the App and get a link for it. That link I placed in one of the sheets in the original spreadsheet, which I used as a data download link. Other then this I didn't find a way to work the security issues around.