# Is there a way to generate a .jpg image of a google sheets chart using scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google sheets I have a tab with a button that calls a script that do some stuff and generates a chart. I would like to add to the end of the script a code that generates and download an image of the generated chart.

In top right of the chart there is an option that does that, so I recorded a macro doing this but nothing was generated.

Couldn't find a way to do that. Any clue?

Thank You

Comment: There’s a get image method for charts that are rendered in HTML

Answer (score 0):

This will put a png image into a Google Doc:

```
function chartImage() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
  .addRange(sheet.getDataRange())
  .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
  .setOption("title", "Dynamic Chart")
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  var img=sheet.getCharts()[0].getBlob().getAs('image/png');
  var doc=DocumentApp.openById('Doc Id');
  doc.getBody().appendImage(img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will get the image saved in your Drive and put the URL in one of your cells in your spreadsheet:

```
function downloadChart() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("Range where the chart is located");
 // Get chart and save it into your Drive
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(chart.getBlob());
  // Set url in one cell and resize the column 
  sheet.getRange(23, 1).setValue(file.getUrl())
  sheet.autoResizeColumn(1);
}
```

As a workaround for a direct download when you click the button, I recommend you to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573055/can-i-download-file-from-url-link-generated-by-google-apps-script) post.

### Docs

- [Create a file in drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app.html#createfileblob)
- [Chart Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts)