# How to download file from a download link on Gmail and uploading it to Google Drive using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to download a file from a download link on Gmail and upload it to Google Drive using the script below:

```
function getGmailData() {

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName([gmail_label]);
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var t = threads.length-1; t >= 0; t--) {
    var messages = threads[t].getMessages();
    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
      var data = messages[m].getPlainBody();
      var urlField = data.indexOf('You can download it here ');
      var url = VBAEquivalents.Mid(data, urlField, 79);
      getFileFromUrl(url);
    }
  }

}

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573055/can-i-download-file-from-url-link-generated-by-google-apps-script
function getFileFromUrl(url) {

  var fileUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var fileBlob = fileUrl.getBlob();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById([folder_id]);
  folder.createFile(fileBlob);

}
```

However, an HTML file is being generated rather than the CSV file. When I manually click on the link to download a file it takes me to Talkdesk. The Save As box automatically pops up as the credentials are cached. Am I missing a step? Or do I need to do it completely different approach/way?

Comment: ` VBAEquivalents.Mid` does not sound like an Apps Script function. What does your url look like? Is it a link to a CSV file? Please provide a sample url if you can.

Comment: You can refer to https://gist.github.com/brucemcpherson/3358690 for the VBAEquivalents. I made it as a library as I use it a lot of times.
It is a link to download the CSV file. Looks something like this: https://www.mytalkdesk.com/reports/executions/7edde1fed0fcd000043a1bd5

Comment: I can confirm that your code correctly saves a csv file from a publicly available url, e.g.  https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv, but mytalkdesk seems to require login / authentication. REad the documentaiton carefully, you might be better of to [send the csv file per email](https://support.talkdesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205776499-Exporting-Detailed-Call-Reports) and retrieve it from the attachemnt.

Comment: Trying to automate the process so we use Scheduled reports. There is a Report Format option, however, the file is not attached to the email. It just sends the link to download just like what I have provided above.

Comment: I cannot open the link you provided. I assume it requires authentication. You need to get informaiton about which kind of authentication mytalkdesk expects. [Here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/third-party-apis) are the possible options.

Comment: Yes, it requires authentication.

This is very helpful! Will look into this and will update you. Thank you!