# My Google app script can successfully iterate and extract file attachments but not hyperlinked attachments. Is there a method I can use for this?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function that successfully extracts file attachments from new emails. But it is unable to detect hyperlinked attachments like this email from our office scanner:

[image]

Would anyone know of an approach to address this?

**UPDATE:**

I found a similar case in [How to download file from a download link on Gmail and uploading it to Google Drive using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329818/how-to-download-file-from-a-download-link-on-gmail-and-uploading-it-to-google-dr)

and revised my code below.
Here's the result:

a) extracting a hyperlinked attachment using this publicly available URL (people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv) as my sample attachment works OK and saves it in my preferred filename, but

b) for the actual email from our scanner I get this error message when it executes UrlFetchApp.fetch(url):

> Exception: Bad request: http://10.87.38.21:8000/cmj/asd/download?dev=...

What could be causing this issue?

(my revised code below):

```
//===================================
function ExtractEmailAttachmentsJP() {
//===================================
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = SS.getSheetByName("UPLOADER");
  var logsheet = SS.getSheetByName("Documents Uploaded");

  TEMPFOLDERID = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('TEMPFOLDERID');
  TEMPFOLDER = DriveApp.getFolderById(TEMPFOLDERID);

  //do not overwrite, just append to the last non-empty (max) row
  var startRow = lastNonblankRow("N",SSID,"UPLOADER")+1
  
  COUNTER = 0;  //initialize file attachment counter

  var gmailLabels  = "PeopleDoc";

  var threads = GmailApp.search("label:" + gmailLabels + " is:Unread", 0, 3);
  
  if (threads.length > 0) {
    
     SS.toast("New emails found. Extracting attachment(s)...");
    
    /*Iterate through the threads of emails*/
    for (var t=0; t<threads.length; t++) {
      var msgs = threads[t].getMessages();

      //Iterate through each mail
      for (var m=0; m<msgs.length; m++) {
          var msg = msgs[m];
          var data = msg.getPlainBody();
          var urlField = data.indexOf('http://');
          var url = data.substr(urlField, 117);

          var fileUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
          var fileBlob = fileUrl.getBlob();

          COUNTER = COUNTER + 1;
          var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(msg.getDate()), "GMT+8", 'dd MMM hh:mm');
          var pdfID = TEMPFOLDER.createFile(fileBlob).setName("attachment" + COUNTER + " " + timestamp).getId();
          
          //show each generic file row by row
          sheet.getRange(startRow-1+COUNTER, 10).setFormula('=HYPERLINK(\"https://drive.google.com/file/d/' + pdfID + '\", \"' + "attachment" + COUNTER + " " + timestamp + '\")');
          sheet.getRange(startRow-1+COUNTER, 15).setValue(pdfID);
          sheet.getRange(startRow-1+COUNTER, 16).setValue("Gmail Inbox");
      }
```

Comment: If you want to retrieve the file from the URL like `http://{ipaddress}/,,,`, at first, how about checking whether the file can be retrieved from the URL using UrlfetchApp?

Comment: I will explore your suggested solution and let you know the results, Tanaike-san. Thank you for your quick response.