# Fetch file from external URL and upload to Google Drive using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm not sure if this is even possible. I'm trying to fetch file that being uploaded to formfacade server via the add-on in google form. I'm using it to allow other non-gmail users to upload file without having to sign-in.

I referred to answer from Mogsdad and dheeraj raj in
[Can I download file from URL link generated by google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573055/can-i-download-file-from-url-link-generated-by-google-apps-script) to use UrlFetchApp to meet this objective. Below are my codes:

Method 1 :

```
    function UrlFile2gdrive() {
     var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var lrow=sheet.getLastRow();
     //var fileURL=sheet.getRange(lrow,2).getValue();
     var fileURL='https://formfacade.com/uploaded/1FAIpQLSfscYq_sbYcT2P3Sj3AvSD2zYKalIM0SKdPTESf1wE9Rq8qew/'
     +'97dc1ee0-f212-11ea-95c3-bdb6c5ab13b3/2124651919/A%20Sample%20PDF.pdf'
     var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}; 
     
     var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL,params);
      Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    var fileBlob=response.getBlob();
    
      
      var folder='0B2b-M7h6xF-Mflk3dGswano2TnJ3dGlmZG8wOUREMFg4blM5SHBuM3lqYmdPOThZSTBTSWs'
    
    
    var filename=fileURL.split("/").pop();
    //var filename=fileURL.split("%2F").pop();
    var file=decodeURIComponent(filename);
      Logger.log("filename : "+file);
      
     
     var newfile=DriveApp.getFolderById(folder).createFile(fileBlob.setName(file));    
     //var newfile=DriveApp.getFolderById(folder).createFile(response.setName(filename));
     
    }
```

Method 2

```
    //api-key : AIzaSyCcbdBCI-Kgcz3tE1N4paeF9a-vdi3Uzz8
    
    //Declare function
    function URL2gdriveWithPswd() {
      //Getting url,existing name and new name for image from the sheet in 
      //variable url, name and new_name respectively
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var row = sh.getLastRow();
      Logger.log(row);
      //for (var i = 2; i <= row; i++) {
    
        /*var url = sh.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
        Logger.log(url);
        var name = sh.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
        var new_name = sh.getRange(i, 4).getValue();*/
      var url = sh.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
        Logger.log(url);
        var filenm=url.split("/").pop();
        var new_name=decodeURIComponent(filenm);
        var name = sh.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
        //var new_name = sh.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
        //Creating authentication token for downloading image, it may not be //required if image can be downloaded without login into
        var user = "dtestsys@gmail.com";
        var password = "1851235656";
        var headers = {
          "Accept": "application/xml",
          "Content-Type": "application/xml",
          "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ":" + password)
        };
        //defining method to download file
        var options = {
          "method": "get",
          "headers": headers
        };
        //Getting folder name where to store downloaded image
        var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('File Uploader (File responses)');
        while (folders.hasNext()) {
          var folder = folders.next();
          Logger.log(folder.getName());
        }
        //Getting response on hit of url using downloading method defined //earlier storing in Blob
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getBlob();
        //Creating image in folder defined with response in blob and logging same file //in log to check, if required
        var file = folder.createFile(response);
        Logger.log(file);
    
        //renaming image
        var images = folder.getFiles();
        while (images.hasNext()) {
          var image = images.next();
          
          file.setName(new_name);
          Logger.log("imagename : "+image.getName());
        }
      //}
    }
```

However, both methods managed to get a file into my gdrive but the content consists of the html codes only (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NYQoMmCQEoP3z6L8niq1mpvIx7xl83zu/view?usp=sharing), which I think the URL passed in google response sheet is just a "mask". I noticed that inside the file has some lines that mentioned api-key and code (next to user email address). Is it possible to achieve my objective? Are those api-key and code would be useful to get authorized to access the file and download it in gdrive?

I rechecked.The link produced and passed into my google sheet response is only the login page that redirects to another XML file. When I copied back the final URL after the original file content is displayed, the URL is as below:
https://storage.googleapis.com/formfacade-public/1FAIpQLSfscYq_sbYcT2P3Sj3AvSD2zYKalIM0SKdPTESf1wE9Rq8qew%2F97dc1ee0-f212-11ea-95c3-bdb6c5ab13b3%2F2124651919%2FA%20Sample%20PDF.pdf?GoogleAccessId=firebase-adminsdk-pve0p%40formfacade.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1599671507&Signature=fBzWej0fEgF6Aw7oCHX%2FTTUfHbcep%2Bj%2B%2FhB3fYFUDeq0SFTuyJ6jTnLWQJmldD6XkVug0%2BNki7ZPNo2ESufvIfQjhVLKXgvp7UiQheJ4GYL%2BtXgFLaUyglgemmfp7KSvIvPxpMcpC2lR8em3E5YIvMRr9tcfzagvusQYHEb9mlD7k833bVoqFUVWuP%2FkP8tl%2BHYVL15kSXAjtFif4QZpu%2FFHwSik89Keo78LKTm0U8hZiAMeYDQZWF6w1pcKpy04md3xKtDPwZYCoUWOOtKkCI6JLskE5HweDvMCGnDbxW8o6SWD%2BIC%2FlaNC6%2BJ81OB10cuRqwQPEc9LnfgCZK7b1A%3D%3D

When I pasted the above link, I got to see as per screenshot below:-
[image: XMLfile formfacade]. So, I'm guessing they don't share direct access link to the uploaded file so that we are left with the option to buy/subscribe the paid version.

Would anyone knows if there's any better altrnative(s) I could use to achieve this objective? Like maybe a link with API-key just like what I learnt from @Tanaike in his previous answer on Convert-API to convert pdf file to PNG? Of course it has some limits for the free version but it still is a very helpful solution.

Comment: Can you provide the specification for downloading the file? For example, can you download the file using curl command? If you can do, can you show it?

Comment: I'm really sorry @Tanaike. I don't know curl. It needs to be in GAS though. The file uploaded by the user must be auto-push as inline image in email to our administrator for verification process. To widen my target scope, I wish to be able to allow non-google account users to upload as well. I found a paid solution though, but I wish to use the free solution (if possible).

Comment: Thank you for replying and additional information. Unfortunately, from your additional information, I couldn't understand about the specification for downloading the file. I deeply apologize for this. But I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning content-type of the blob anywhere. But if you do the naming right it would not matter. In method 1 you are trying to set a name on the blob when you should be setting it on the file created from the Blob.

Try setting the name on the file ***after*** creating it.

#### Example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var url  ="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  console.log(response.getResponseCode());
  var blob=response.getAs('application/pdf');
  var folder = "<SOME-FOLDER-ID>";
  var fileName=decodeURIComponent(url.split("/").pop());
  
  console.log("File named : "+fileName);
  var file=DriveApp.getFolderById(folder).createFile(blob);
  // Set the name to the created file after creating it!
  file.setName(fileName); 
}
```

For reference see class [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file).

Comment: your code produced the same output for my file. I suspect that the URL link being auto-produced by formfacade is not the direct link to the file but I cannot control that part if I wish to use their add-on for file upload. What I need is to get the xml (maybe) based on the API-key and code that was captured in the doc after I transferred the so-called file into my gdrive. I want to check if there's anyone out there who may have the solution before I give up and say this will never work unless I upgrade as a paid member (maybe).

Comment: Updated my answer. Use `getAs('application/pdf')` to get the blob.

Comment: your code produced the pdf file alright. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hWoH2K6zkvJdOHegQD1j5toNizCJ79mj/view?usp=sharing but the content is the webpage that I would see first before it redirects me to the original document. Just now, I rechecked the URL after the original doc is displayed. At the browser, I just noticed that the URL has some extension link like XML (has credentials and token expiry datetime). When I copy+paste that link in the browser directly, I saw it shows as per screenshot in my edited question above.

Comment: Yes, the file is not public. So indeed nothing you can do. To download it for free, or without the credentials...

Comment: Yea. you actually gave a solution for the non-restricted file from external file though. So, I am not quite sure how should I rate your answer ya?

Comment: I think I am just gonna rate your answer with tick because my question title didn't mentioned it is specifically for URL from formfacade. Anyway, thanks for ur help and effort.