# Download file from URL link in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44056407/17040148

I am trying to download an image from the url in the sheet which are submitted from a google form.
The code is found from the source, but I only manage to get the file download in to the correct folder and name instead of getting image. I am getting html text in the image.
Not sure which part have I done wrong.

**Result I get**:

[execution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUEtq.png)

[File storage image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPsGq.png)

[Image downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8rjW.png)

I only add in detail in the `xxxxxxx` field.

```
//Declare function
function downloadFile() {
  //Getting url,existing name and new name for image from the sheet in 
  //variable url, name and new_name respectively
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sh.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(row);
  for (var i = 2; i <= row; i++) {

    var url = sh.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
    Logger.log(url);
    var name = sh.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
    var new_name = sh.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
    //Creating authentication token for downloading image, it may not be //required if image can be downloaded without login into
    var user = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    var password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    var headers = {
      "Accept": "application/xml",
      "Content-Type": "application/xml",
      "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ":" + password)
    };
    //defining method to download file
    var options = {
      "method": "get",
      "headers": headers
    };
    //Getting folder name where to store downloaded image
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('xxxxxxxxxx');
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
      var folder = folders.next();
      Logger.log(folder.getName());
    }
    //Getting response on hit of url using downloading method defined //earlier storing in Blob
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getBlob();
    //Creating image in folder defined with response in blob and logging same file //in log to check, if required
    var file = folder.createFile(response);
    Logger.log(file);

    //renaming image
    var images = folder.getFiles();
    while (images.hasNext()) {
      var image = images.next();
      file.setName(new_name);
      Logger.log(image.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

**Also, how can I set it to ONLY download the URL from the new form submitted.**

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the specification for downloading the data from your URLs and your tested situations, when you confirmed whether your request header is valid for downloading the data from the URL, what result did you obtain? I'm worried about this.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for assisting! I have set up an example and test account. I have upload an apple logo in the link. try see if you can download it

url: 
https://formfacade.com/uploaded/1FAIpQLSe2gyMbwPgTRC4_okcLK82o5HjQt6gCQWyb3-LUPW-V0e7_tg/-Mst382pQX0Gtgazf1mu/846219762/apple%20logo.png

user: testingdownloadimage@gmail.com
pass: Testingaccount123

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample file. When I tested your sample file using your request, I could obtain the same result as you. From this situation, I think that the reason for your issue is your request. But I'm not sure about the specification of your site. So I would like to recommend checking the specification for downloading the file from the site again and modifying your request.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am new to script. How can I check the specification for downloading the file?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your new question of `How can I check the specification for downloading the file?`, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about the information of the URL. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. if you come across anything then you think can help me with this, kindly let me know again.. Thank you